# Having Trouble Breaking Down The Structure Of This Sentence

Tags: particle-の, particle-を

This is a sentence I've encountered in my studies:

> ウィーナーを生のまま食べました

It means something like "The sausage remained raw and I ate it." However, I'm confused as to why it's structured like this. From what I've looked up on the genitive case, it's supposed to affect the *following* noun. However, in this situation 生 seems to be modifying a *preceding* noun. Furthermore, I think it might not be a genitive case because the rules of using まま state that if it's preceded by a noun you need to put a の between them. So, does that mean that the を actually belongs to 生 and not 食べました (via marking the direct object)? Lastly, wouldn't it make more sense to put the 生の in front of ウィーナー?

Comment: 「ウィーナー」って？「ウィ**ン**ナー」？

Comment: @Chocolate I hadn't thought about that difference.  I just assumed the OP given the correct expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of this sentence is

> ウインナー を食べました

which just means, "I ate the sausage".

In this context

> 生のまま

works as an adverb describing the manner in which the sausage was eaten.  This may come across a bit strange, but まま is a noun essentially meaning *manner*.  Unlike what you might expect, you can just use the bare word まま without additional particles to get this *adverbial* function.

Also in this case 生 is read なま.  It is grammatically treated as a noun.  In particular, as a noun, it doesn't govern an object as a verb would.  Thus を cannot be tied to it; を must be tied with the verb.  The only verb present is 食べました.

As a second example, you can say

> 帽子をかぶったまま部屋に入った

> They entered the room wearing their hats